# completing squares in positive definite matrices

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

n the following question, I had a solution by using determinant test but my instructor wants me to solve this problem by using energy test.

> $$B= \begin{bmatrix}
>        -1 & \alpha & -1 \\
>         \alpha & -4 & \alpha \\
>       -1 & \alpha &-1  \\
>       \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Determine, without computing eigenvalues, the interval of $\alpha$ for which they are
>
> 1. positive definite
> 2. negative definite
> 3. positive semidefinite
> 4. negative semidefinite
> 5. indefinite.
>
> First I calculated $x^T Ax$ as following:
>
> $$
> x^T Ax = \begin{bmatrix}  x_{1} & x_{2} & x_{3} \\ \end{bmatrix} \cdot B \cdot  \begin{bmatrix}  x_{1}  \\x_{2}  \\x_{3}  \\\end{bmatrix}
> $$
>
> Then I get the following;
>
> $-x_{1}^2+2\alpha x_{1}x_{2}-2x_{1}x_{3}-4x_{2}^2+2\alpha x_{2}x_{3}-x_{3}^2$
>
> After this point, I could not complete squares and could not make an evaluation about the definiteness of the matrix. Could you please
>   help me about completing squares?

Comment: I formatted half the question. Please format the rest.

Comment: So, is it $a$ or $\alpha$? Confusing!

Comment: I tried to fix mistakes in latex but it did not reflect here. Is it readable now? Could you please help me about this question?

Comment: Why are you undoing my work? Do you think my time is free?

Comment: I am sorry, I am new in StackExchange and still trying to learn. I am still at the very beginning. If you could help me about improving myself, I would be appreciated to you.

Comment: I already showed you what to do. I have no interest in spending more time on this. Check the edit history.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo your reaction to the asker's (apparently sincere) attempts to format their post seems disproportionate and unkind.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I am truly appreciated to your kindness :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
\begin{aligned}
\pmatrix{-1&a&-1\\ a&-4&a\\ -1&a&-1}
&=-\pmatrix{1&-a&1\\ -a&4&-a\\ 1&-a&1}\\
&=-\pmatrix{1\\ -a\\ 1}\pmatrix{1&-a&1}
-(4-a^2)\pmatrix{0\\ 1\\ 0}\pmatrix{0&1&0}
\end{aligned}
and hence $x^TBx=-(x_1-ax_2+x_3)^2 - (4-a^2)x_2^2$. Therefore $B$ is never positive semidefinite, and it is negative semidefinite (resp. negative definite) if and only if $4-a^2$ is nonnegative (resp. negative).

Answer (score 0):

One approach to completing the squares here is to deal with each cross-term individually.  For instance, we can absorb the $x_1x_2$ term into a square as follows:
$$
-x_{1}^2+ \underline{2\alpha x_{1}x_{2}}-2x_{1}x_{3}-4x_{2}^2+2\alpha x_{2}x_{3}-x_{3}^2 =\\
-(x_{1}^2 - 2\alpha x_{1}x_{2})-2x_{1}x_{3}-4x_{2}^2+2\alpha x_{2}x_{3}-x_{3}^2 =\\ 
-(x_{1}^2 - 2\alpha x_{1}x_{2} + \alpha^2 x_2^2) + \alpha^2x_2^2-2x_{1}x_{3}-4x_{2}^2+2\alpha x_{2}x_{3}-x_{3}^2 =\\
-(x_1 - \alpha x_2)^2 + \alpha^2x_2^2-2x_{1}x_{3}-4x_{2}^2+2\alpha x_{2}x_{3}-x_{3}^2 =\\
-(x_1 - \alpha x_2)^2 - 2x_{1}x_{3}+(\alpha^2-4)x_{2}^2+2\alpha x_{2}x_{3}-x_{3}^2
$$
Once you have moved every cross-term into a square in this fashion, you will have a sum of squares.